# Splitting Vector into Sub-vectors MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math

I am trying to figure out how to split a vector in matlab into subvectors.

I am solving a differential equation numerically using `dde23`. When You do this the length of the solution vector changes. Thus, I am finding it not so easy to use the mat2cell command that many people suggest.

All I am trying to do is split (as evenly as possible) a vector of length N into an arbitrary amount of sub-vectors whose length may vary depending on the length of the time vector. I am doing this so then I can find the maximum value of each vector on in each interval.

Comment: Please provide sample input/s & output  and what you have tried. Please [edit] your question in the form of a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, maybe you can try to split it by using code below

```
dataset=[ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]

     splitpoint = randi[2 length(dataset)-1]

     subset1 = dataset(1,1:splitpoint)

     splitpoint = randi[length(subset1)+1 length(dataset)-1]

     subset2 = dataset(1,length(subset1)+1:splitpoint)
```

After that you can choose where to finish and accept rest of it for last subset or you can define one list to hold each subset in the row of the list. So you can define while loop to handle it automatically by defining stop_criteria.